# Use JAVA to open a CSV file (using JXL library)

Tags: java, excel, outlook, jxl

I am truly a green horn to JAVA. I am trying use JAVA (JXL) to do the following: 
1. Open a csv file in Excel that is located at "C:\Test" (Could I treat this like an excel file to be opened with JXL?) 
2. Check Cell A1 
If A1 is empty, close the file and end the routine. If A1 is not empty, go to step 3. 
3. Close the csv file and send an Outlook email to 3 people stating "Event is now happening"

I assume there is probably another API library needed to work with Microsoft Outlook

I have been using Netbeans

I appreciate any help!!! 
Dave

Comment: Try using apache POI for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

 public class ReadExcel {

 private String inputFile;

 public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
this.inputFile = inputFile;
}

public void read() throws IOException  {
File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
Workbook w;
try {
  w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
  // Get the first sheet
  Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
  // Loop over first 10 column and lines

  for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
      Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
      CellType type = cell.getType();
      if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
        System.out.println("I got a label "
            + cell.getContents());
      }

      if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
        System.out.println("I got a number "
            + cell.getContents());
      }

    }
  }
} catch (BiffException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();
test.setInputFile("c:/temp/lars.xls");
test.read();
}

} `
```

This is what you should do - where inputFile is the location - C:\Users\Bob\test.csv

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge but where do I put "C:\Users\Bob\test.csv". I have numbered the lines below. What line?10  public class ReadExcel {
11 
12  private String inputFile;
13 
14  public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
15 this.inputFile = inputFile;
16 }
17 
18 public void read() throws IOException  {
19 File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
20 Workbook w;
21 try {
22   w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
23   // Get the first sheet
24   Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
25   // Loop over first 10 column and lines

Comment: if you look at the main method, you can see that I do test.setInputFile("C:\...."); that is where you should type the location of your file location.

Comment: Now I have another problem. When I run the java, I get the following error:run:
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
 at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
 at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
 at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
 at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
 at jxl_polling_open_csv.JXL_Polling_Open_csv.read(JXL_Polling_Open_csv.java:24)
 at jxl_polling_open_csv.JXL_Polling_Open_csv.main(JXL_Polling_Open_csv.java:53)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, **you can't use JXL to read CSV files**.

I faced the same problem, and this is what I came up with:

- If your CSV file has less than 65,536 rows and less than 256 columns; you could just save it as an XLS file, and JXL should work.
- Otherwise, check out this post on [Accessing File Formats](https://coderanch.com/wiki/660373/Accessing-File-Formats) for other methods.